# Suggestions for a good vector editor

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, graphics

I'm new to macOS (Sierra) and am searching a simple vector editing tool.

Previously, on Linux I used Inkscape. However, on Mac the base on XQuartz is hard for me to use.

Does anyone know of a better alternative?

Comment: Have you seen this site? http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-vector-software-mac-designers-budget/

Comment: Finally, i've use inkscape from brew cask. `brew cask install inkscape`

Answer (score 1):

there is a native  mac version
 otherwise I recomend Afinity Designer
[inkscape dmg](https://inkscape.org/en/~su_v/%E2%98%85inkscape-osxmenu-r12922-gtk2)

Comment: This is the version that runs on XQuartz that OP is specifically saying they don't like.

Answer (score 1):

[**Sketch**](https://sketchapp.com) is my favourite vector editor, providing all the features you could want in a vector editor, supporting import and export of vector content in a variety of formats.

[image]
[image]